# Lazy view loading on Android ScrollView

Tags: android

Is there a solution for lazy-loading on Android ScrollView?

I have a set of different views (that have nothing in common) which are displayed in a vertical sequence in a ScrollView.

Those items cannot be placed in a ListView because they all hold different layouts.

Those layouts are quite complex, and therefore, currently blocks UI when a fragment is opened. What would work better is if it only loaded the visible views first.

Comment: Use new thread to load views, have you tried?

Comment: Android native libraries are not thread-safe and UI manipulation must be on the main thread.

Comment: You can you Handler to post a Runable object that do UI task from working thread